# I have to write a Mongo Query to extract the values in a nested dictionary

Tags: mongodb

```
{ 'key1': value1,
          'key2': { 'key2_1': value2_1,
                    'key2_2': value2_2 }}
```

I have this JSON, say i want to extract just value2_1 and value2_2 .... 
What can I do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the projection operator to return just the values within the subdocument.

```
db.test.insert({ 'key1': "value1",           'key2': { 'key2_1': "value2_1",                     'key2_2': "value2_2" }})
          WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 }) 

db.test.find({},{"key2.key2_1":1,_id:0})
          { "key2" : { "key2_1" : "value2_1" } }

db.test.find({},{"key2.key2_1":1,"key2.key2_2":1,_id:0})
          { "key2" : { "key2_1" : "value2_1", "key2_2" : "value2_2" } }
```